# Uncatalog objects that can not be found

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I'm updating my Plone website from 4.2.x to 4.3.x and I'm getting quite a lot of errors like:

```
INFO plone.app.upgrade Reindex Description index with I18N Case Normalizer
ERROR Zope.ZCatalog reindexIndex could not resolve an object from the uid '/RANDOM/PATH'
```

Checking the website for that path indeed is not there anymore.

So how can one get rid of those objects before actually running the upgrade?

Or actually, given the upgrade method (https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/blob/master/plone/app/upgrade/v43/alphas.py#L56) which basically goes over all indexes on the catalog and then does the following:

```
catalog.manage_clearIndex([index_id])
catalog.reindexIndex(index_id,aq_get(context, 'REQUEST', None))
```

I don't need to do anything because the manage_clearIndex already removes everything and the reindexIndex only indexes the ones that can be found?

Comment: Before upgrading try to do a clear and rebuild. Not clear only a specific index, clear the hole catalog.

Comment: @Mathias thanks, yes I will try, I forgot to say that our database is huuuuuuge, millions of objects, so having to wake up all of them is not a great thing for us... specially with conflict errors

Comment: So it would be probably better to make a query over the hole database and try to get the object from a brain (`brain.getObject()`), catch the exception and then manually (script or by hand) delete the brain from the catalog.

Comment: well queuering the hole catalog also wakes up every obj :-)

Comment: For a similar case (huge db) I developer an experimental add-on: https://github.com/RedTurtle/rt.friendlyzcatalog
This helped me in unindex lost objects. Please note: evaluate it but use at your own risk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the problem is easier to solve than it seemed: you only need to uncatalog that object and that will be it.

So for example this code will do it:

```python
catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
for brain in catalog(portal_type='Discussion Item'):
    try:
        comment = brain.getObject()
    except KeyError:
        catalog.uncatalog_object(brain.getPath())
```

Source: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/catalog.html

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of situations, [collective.catalogcleanup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.catalogcleanup) may be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, but it was a little bit more complicated as the error was showing up only when using `sort_on='getObjPositionInParent'` on the catalog query.

I ended up by parsing the exception message and removing the offending brains from the catalog using this code:

```py
while True:
    try:
        results = catalog(path='/Plone/foo', sort_on='getObjPositionInParent')
    except ValueError as e:
        id_ = e.message.split('"')[1]
        results = catalog(id=id_)
        print 'uncatalogging: {0} ({1} objects)'.format(id_, len(results))
        [catalog.uncatalog_object(b.getPath()) for b in results]
    else:
        print 'done!'
        break
```

It took some time but at the end I was able to clean the catalog.